# Properly Importing v3 of JointJS

Tags: javascript, jointjs

When working with version 2.2.1 of JointJS I imported it like this:

```
import { default as joint } from "jointjs";
```

Now I'm working with version 3.0.2.  "joint" from the line above is undefined.  The import no longer works.  I noticed in the release notes for JointJS 3.0.0:

> Notable changes - 
>   full support for ES Modules

How should I import it now?

Comment: You no longer need to use default, instead you can use a * or import it as an object directly without the braces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is no default import anymore, 
`import * as joint from 'jointjs'` works just fine. If need a smaller bundle you can cherry pick parts you actually need:

```
import { dia } from 'jointjs/src/core.mjs';
// import shapes you need 
import * as standard from 'jointjs/src/shapes/standard.mjs';

const graph = new dia.Graph([], { cellNamespace: { standard } });
new dia.Paper({
    cellViewNamespace: { standard },
    el: document.getElementById('paper'),
    width: 500, height: 500,
    model: graph
});

const rectangle = new standard.Rectangle().size(200, 200).position(100, 100).addTo(graph)
```

Please note you need to be careful with the `cellViewNamespace` for the `dia.Paper` and `cellNamespace` option for the `dia.Graph` in this setup. Otherwise, you could encounter the `Uncaught Error: dia.ElementView: markup required error`

runnig this snippet is a quick check you've set up the namespaces correctly:

```
const cells = JSON.stringify(graph.toJSON());
graph.clear();
graph.fromJSON(JSON.parse(cells));
```

Comment: vt, thank you for your post. My team has to convert an implementation of JointJS from v2.2.1 to v3.0.2.  The people who wrote this implementation are gone. The namespaces you listed above aren't used and I'm hitting the error you mentioned (markup required error).